# Send mass email with attachment (attachment need to select from vf page)

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

i have a vf page with email template pick list user able to select email template

Choose file : user able to upload a file attachment from his computer.

there is a command button send email . once clicking on send email need to send email with selected template with email attachment .
please help me on this..

sample code :

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="WrapperClsOnContactMass">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages >
    </apex:pageMessages>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperObj}" var="x">
                <apex:column value="{!x.conobj.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!x.conobj.email}"/>
                <apex:column >
                  <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!x.checkBox }"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:commandButton value="SendEmail" action="{!sendEmail}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public with sharing class WrapperClsOnContactMass {

    public List<WrapperClassEx> WrapperList{get;set;}

    public WrapperClsOnContactMass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public List<WrapperClassEx> getwrapperObj(){
        List<Contact> conList =[select id, name, email from contact limit 5];   
        WrapperList = new List<WrapperClassEx>();
        for(Contact con: conList){


            WrapperList.add(New WrapperClassEx(con,false));  
        }
        return WrapperList;  
    }

    public class WrapperClassEx{

       public WrapperClassEx(){

        }
       public Contact conObj{get;set;}
       public Boolean checkBox{get;set;}
       public WrapperClassEx(Contact conRec, boolean SelectedBox){               
          conObj= conRec;
          checkBox = SelectedBox;
       }
    }

    public void sendEmail(){
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstEmailId=new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for(WrapperClassEx w: WrapperList){
            if(w.checkBox == true){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {w.conObj.Email});
                mail.setReplyTo('ukla@magicsw.com');
                mail.setplainTextBody('Hello');
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Your Company Name');
                mail.setSubject('Test Email From Force.com Sites');
                lstEmailId.add(mail);                        
            }
        }
        if(lstEmailId.size()>0){
            try{
                Messaging.sendEmail(lstEmailId);
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Confirm,'Sent!'));
            }Catch(Exception ee){
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,ee.getMessage()));
            }

        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: where is the VF markup for selecting the email template? and corresponding controller code?  A simple `apex:selectList` with `apex:selectOption`s should do - see the VF Developer Guide

Comment: I notice your title mentions "Mass email". You'll want to look at the Messaging Namespace in the Apex Developer Guide since I see you're using the `SingleEmailMessage` method. The `MassEmailMessage` method requires the use of a template and won't work with `setPlainTextBody`. See the `EmailFileAttachment` Class for methods to help create your code for the attachment.